# Reverse slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to reverse slideToggle from top downwards. Instead of revealing what the element is, I want it to slide it in from the top.

I'm not sure how to explain so here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6E7f/.
If you click on "header" it will **reveal** the header instead of **sliding** it in from topdown.
If you click on "footer" you can see that the footer is sliding from bottom upwards. And this is what I want to do for the header but ofcourse reversed. Does anyone how to do this with "slideToggle" or am I stuck with "animate"

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="header">header</a>
<a href="#" class="footer">footer</a>
<header>
    <h1>header</h1>
</header>


<footer>
    <h1>footer</h1>
</footer>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.header').on('click', function(){
        $('header').slideToggle(200);
    });

    $('.footer').on('click', function(){
        $('footer').slideToggle(200);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it slides down, done with:
- removing display:hidden from the header class (only for convenience)
- animating "margin-top" from -100px to 0px
- using hand written toggle function

You use absolute positioning I left it how it was. If you want header to slidedown under the links, use some wrapper div with overflow-y: hidden ,  etc.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var a = true;
 $('.header').on('click', function(){
        if(a){
            $('header').animate({"margin-top":"0px"});
        }else{
            $('header').animate({"margin-top":"-100px"});
        }
        a=!a;
 });

 $('.footer').on('click', function(){
  $('footer').slideToggle(200);
 });
    
});
```

```css
header{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

footer{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="header">header</a>
<a href="#" class="footer">footer</a>
<header style="margin-top:-100px">
    <h1>header</h1>
</header>


<footer>
    <h1>footer</h1>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

updated on Fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/6Zt9A/

```
<h1 style="display: none" id="header_wrapper">header</h1>
<a href="#" class="header">header</a>
<a href="#" class="footer">footer</a>
<h1 style="display: none" id="footer_wrapper">footer</h1>

jQuery(function ($) {
$('.header').on('click', function() {
    $('#header_wrapper').slideToggle(200);
})
$('.footer').on('click', function() {
    $('#footer_wrapper').slideToggle(200);
})
```

});`

Comment: nope this isn't it. The position of my header and footer are correct. What I'm trying to do are the movement of the header. I want the header go down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css and effect for header to slide down.

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var posy;
    $('.header').on('click', function(){
        posy = (posy==50?-50:50);
        $('header').animate(
        {
            top:posy
        }, 300);
        //$('header').slideToggle(200);
    });

    $('.footer').on('click', function(){
        $('footer').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top:-50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

footer {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

See Demo http://jsfiddle.net/h6E7f/4/